# jquery - Read data from txt file and assign to different variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

Say I have this txt file, and inside it is:

title(Here is the title that gets inserted into the title element)
body(Here is the body text that gets inserted into the body element)

and I want jquery to insert the title into the title element and the body into the body element. Is this possible, or do I need to use separate txt files for each content? I am new to jquery so this isn't very obvious to me.

I have this code so far:

```js
$(function(){
    $( "#title" ).load( "content/home.txt" );
    $( "#body" ).load( "content/home.txt" );
});
```

If this was difficult to understand  I hope this code would better explain it.

Comment: Javascript does not have the ability to read from your filesystem without user interaction. You would have to provide a file selection dialog, then the user would have to select the file to open.

Comment: Checkout this link http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-read-text-file/ Once you get the file loaded, then you can apply it to your DOM.

Comment: If this is a content on your server use JSON objects and Ajax approach.Will be more efficient

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell This is inside the ftp along with the website itself, and I've tested it and it reads the txt file no problem.

Comment: Ah I was mistaken to think that you wanted to read it from the users computer, not the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

Have a file (doc.json) with contents:

```
{
    "title" : "some title",
    "body" : "some body text"
}
```

And on your page

```
$.getJSON( "doc.json", function( data ) {
     $("#title").text(data.title);
     $("#body").text(data.body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been such a hard task for me and you just solved it. This is by far the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change your home.txt file to an html file, and have it contain something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Foo!</title>
</head>
<body>Bar!</body>
</html>
```

Then change your code to this

```
$(function(){
    $( "#title" ).load( "content/home.html title" );
    $( "#body" ).load( "content/home.html body" );
});
```

Alternatively you could store your file as a JSON object, load it with $.ajax, and then use those values. This would make it so your text file doesn't have to be valid html.

Either way will probably work. However this is a solution that is probably better suited to a server side language.

Comment: Not sure how to store something as a json object, how would I go about this?

Comment: A json object is just the object notation of javascript: { Title: 'Foo!', Body: 'Content!' }

Answer (score 0):

Your textfile could have the title, body separated by a delimiter. So for example your .txt file would look like this:

```
// = is the delimiter
title=body
```

Jquery will read the file contents into a variable (using $.get). We separate the title and body into an array by using the split() function:

```
function ReadFile() {
        $.get("test.txt", function (response) {
            var arrStr = response.split("=");
            $('#txtbox1').val(arrStr[0]);   //title
            $('#txtbox2').val(arrStr[1]);   //body
        });
    }
```